# syntax error occured in combining json string in python

Tags: python, json

I have to create a json string with combined sub string.  i coded as below

```
import json

s1 = {'name':'s1','age':15}
s2 = {'name':'s2','age':10}
s3 = {'name':'s3','age':12}
s = {'class':1}

master = {s,'students':[s1,s2,s3]}
print(master)
```

i got syntax error in line

```
master = {s,'students':[s1,s2,s3]}
```

I like to get out as follows

```
{'class':1,'students':[{'name':'s1','age':15},{'name':'s2','age':10},{'name':'s3','age':12}]}
```

Kindly help.  I am newbie in python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
master = {**s,'students':[s1,s2,s3]}
```

This will expand `s` into its keys and values so that they are directly part of `master`. Otherwise you have to specify keys and values directly with `:` between.

Note that this only works in Python 3.

Comment: Your solution is simple and i am using python 3.8.0.  I accepting your solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, it working in Python2:

```py
import json

s1 = {'name':'s1','age':15}
s2 = {'name':'s2','age':10}
s3 = {'name':'s3','age':12}
s = {'class':1}
students = {'students':[s1,s2,s3]}

master = dict(s.items() + students.items())
print(master)
```

And this will working for python2 and python3

```py
master = dict(list(s.items()) + list(students.items()))
```

Answer (score 2):

One more way to achieve this

```
s1 = {'name':'s1','age':15}
s2 = {'name':'s2','age':10}
s3 = {'name':'s3','age':12}
s = {'class':1}

master = {}
master.update(s)
master.update({'students':[s1,s2,s3]})
```

This should work with both the python versions

Answer (score 1):

master = {**s,'students':[s1,s2,s3]}